# Step layout option display name not visible

Tags: sharepoint

I'm working on sharepoint and I'm trying to add multiple collapsed section in a page. I create a blank new page and a section. When I tried to modify the section layout option I'm not able to add a display name. The field is not visible. A little bit stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: View image below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image]

Please clear the browser cache and open a new inPrivate window to compare the result.

Comment: Wooowww you save my day. Thank you so much.